# how to apply two types to orElse() in Optional

Tags: kotlin

I want to use orElse() function in Optional, but the first half "engineRepository.findById(engineId)" return Model, and second half return list of Model, how can I make the result return List?

I tried to add listof() to the first half, but I can't use orElse() anymore, how to do that?

```
var ModelList: List<Model> = try {
            EngineRepository.findById(engineId).orElse(EngineRepository.findAllByEnvironment(environment)))

}
```

```
@Repository
interface EngineRepository : MongoRepository<Model, String> {
    fun findAllByEnvironment(environment: String):List<Model>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should indeed use `listOf`, but instead of passing the entire expression of `EngineRepository.findById(engineId)` to it, you should apply it to the `Model` wrapped inside the `Optional` returned by `findById`. To do that, use `map`:

```
EngineRepository.findById(engineId)
    .map(::listOf)
    .orElse(EngineRepository.findAllByEnvironment(environment))
```

Note that this will execute `findAllByEnvironment` whether or not `findById` returned an `Optional.empty()`. If you don't want that, you should use `orElseGet`:

```
.orElseGet { EngineRepository.findAllByEnvironment(environment) }
```

Comment: I needed orElseThrow. Your post helped me to realize I need to use curly braces: repo.findById(id).orElseThrow{Exception("Model not found")}